# SQLAlchemy: Rollback transaction in SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, rollback

How am I supposed to rollback a transaction after it has been committed to a SQLite database?

Here's my toy code. I would have expected the very last print statement to show an empty list.

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine, select
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "Users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User(id={self.id!r}, name={self.name!r})"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    engine = create_engine("sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:", future=True)

    Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

    with Session(engine) as session:

        test_user = User(name="John")

        session.add(test_user)
        session.commit()

        print(f"DB content after commit: {session.execute(select(User)).scalar()}")
        # DB content after commit: User(id=1, name='John')

        session.rollback()  # not working as expected
        print(f"DB content after rollback: {session.execute(select(User)).scalar()}")
        # DB content after rollback: User(id=1, name='John')
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: My objective is to bring the database back into the state that it was in before the commit.

Comment: Use `session.delete(test_user)` followed by `session.commit()`

Comment: Using `session.flush()` instead of `session.commit()` will send the INSERT statement to SQLite without committing the transaction, thereby allowing you to `.rollback()`.

Answer (score 0):

[Savepoint](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#savepoint-support) allow you to roll back to a pre-commit state after a commit, but as shown in the documentation linked above, even when using pysqlite, it doesn't work as desired unless you apply a workaround.

> SQLite supports SAVEPOINTs, which only function once a transaction is begun. SQLAlchemy’s SAVEPOINT support is available using the Connection.begin_nested() method at the Core level, and Session.begin_nested() at the ORM level. However, SAVEPOINTs won’t work at all with pysqlite unless workarounds are taken.

### PostgreSQL

With PostgreSQL, you can add a savepoint and rollback by just adding `session.begin_nested()` to your python code.

```
test_db_url = "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres"

create_database(test_db_url)

engine = create_engine(test_db_url, future=True)

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

with Session(engine) as session:

    session.begin_nested()

    test_user = User(name="John")

    session.add(test_user)
    session.commit()

    print(f"DB content after commit: {session.execute(select(User)).scalar()}")
    # DB content after commit: User(id=1, name='John')

    session.rollback()  # not working as expected
    print(f"DB content after rollback: {session.execute(select(User)).scalar()}")
    # DB content after rollback: User(id=1, name='John')

drop_database(test_db_url)
```

Result:

```
DB content after commit: User(id=1, name='John')
DB content after rollback: None
```

### SQLite

As mentioned above, a workaround is needed.

You can do this by registering two event listeners (`connect`, `begin`) with engine and adding `session.begin_nested()` as shown below.

```
test_db_url = "sqlite+pysqlite:///:memory:"

engine = create_engine(test_db_url, future=True, echo=False)

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

@event.listens_for(engine, "connect")
def do_connect(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    # disable pysqlite's emitting of the BEGIN statement entirely.
    # also stops it from emitting COMMIT before any DDL.
    dbapi_connection.isolation_level = None

@event.listens_for(engine, "begin")
def do_begin(conn):
    # emit our own BEGIN
    conn.exec_driver_sql("BEGIN")

with Session(engine) as session:

    session.begin_nested()

    test_user = User(name="John")

    session.add(test_user)
    session.commit()

    print(f"DB content after commit: {session.execute(select(User)).scalar()}")
    # DB content after commit: User(id=1, name='John')

    session.rollback()  # not working as expected
    print(f"DB content after rollback: {session.execute(select(User)).scalar()}")
    # DB content after rollback: User(id=1, name='John')
```

Result:

```
DB content after commit: User(id=1, name='John')
DB content after rollback: None
```

For more information, see the following links. [here](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/discussions/7723)